I couldn't open a "JPEG" image using "filedialog" module
def open_func():
    global image0
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="E:/pictures",title="Select an image",filetypes=(("all files","*.*"),("jpeg files",'*.jpeg')))
    lbl = Label(root , text=root.filename).pack()
    image0 = root.filename
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image0))

I tried this code to select and open an "JPEG" image but it kept showing me this error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 240: character maps to <undefined>


Image.open wants the name of a file, but you are asking Tkinter to open the file for you and give back the actual file object. And it opened the file in text mode. You can get the name back from the file (as in the linked duplicate), but you should probably just use .askopenfilename instead in the first place. There is probably a better duplicate for this issue but I was unable to find it.
